# Core Data: prevent deleting of shared entities

Tags: ios, core-data

This is something about Core Data I quite don't understand yet.

Consider the following model:

Library <-->  Book  <<-->> Author

At one point the user decides to delete a book from a library, however the book shares an author with another book. What will happen with that shared author, how do I prevent it from being deleted from the store along with the to-be-deleted book?

Comment: How have you configured the deletion rules at the moment?

Comment: As far as I know I have not set up any rules for deletion.

Comment: Default deletion rule is nullify. Don't have to worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, ensure all of your relationships have inverses set (your little diagram has no book -> library).

Each end of a relationship has a `delete rule` which describes what happens when the other end of the relationship is deleted. This is what you should configure. The default is `Nullify`, which means that deleting a book will just remove that book from the list of books known by the author. The author will not be deleted.

Check the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdRelationships.html) for full details on the delete rules. You might want to consider, for example, setting the rule to `Cascade` on the library and the author such that if the library is deleted everything else is too (would require additional relationship from library to authors) and deleting an author will delete all of their books.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the arrow. So if I understand correctly, if I delete a book when the delete rule with author is 'nullify', the authors of that book will not be deleted, even when that's the only book they belong to and they will be 'dangling' ? And if the rule is 'cascade', all authors of that book will be deleted, even if they also belong to another book that is not deleted?

Comment: 'dangling' only because you have no other relationships - the object remains in the data store though, yes. For 'cascade', yes - be careful when setting this, particularly on to-many relationships...

Comment: Got ya. So if I delete a book, I need to check if any of the authors is 'dangling', and if so, delete these as well. I probably need a fetch request with some clever predicate for this (find all authors that are unique to the book to be deleted), or are there other means to find this info?

Comment: Use the relationships, before you delete, if the count of books for an author is 1 then when you delete that book take the author too

Comment: Maybe I can put that logic in `prepareForDeletion` of Author? So eg if count of books is 1, then delete self, or something like that?

Comment: You could add it to `prepareForDeletion` Of Book, yes